# Django Restframework _ custom authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wrote some code for custom authentication with this structure:
serializers.py

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_token = serializers.CharField()
    phonenumber = serializers.CharField()
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
```

views .py

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        phonenumber = request.data.get('phonenumber', None)
        first_token = request.data.get('first_token', None)
        try:
            x = User.objects.get(phonenumber=phonenumber)
        except x.DoesNotExist:
            return Response('user does not exists')
        if first_token == x.first_token.token:
            user = authenticate(phonenumber=phonenumber)
            login_user = login(request, user)
            user_info = {
                'phonenumber': user.phonenumber,
                'username': user.username,
                'token': user.token,
                'is_admin':user.is_admin,
            }

            return Response(user_info, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

so, authentication and login is successful and user logs in. but when i try to go another page testframework doesnt store the authentication. I made a custom authentication already .
auth.py

```
class PhoneAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    authentication_header_prefix = 'Token'
    def authenticate(self, request):
        request.user = None
        auth_header = authentication.get_authorization_header(request).split()
        auth_header_prefix = self.authentication_header_prefix.lower()
        if not auth_header:
            return None
        if len(auth_header) == 1:
            return None
        elif len(auth_header) > 2:
            return None
        prefix = auth_header[0].decode('utf-8')
        token = auth_header[1].decode('utf-8')
        if prefix.lower() != auth_header_prefix:
            return None
        return self._authenticate_credentials(request, token)

    def _authenticate_credentials(self, request, token):
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
        except:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("invalid authentication . could not decode token")
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=payload['id'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
        return(user, token)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to [subscribe](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/views.py) the view `ObtainAuthToken` that is default of [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#by-exposing-an-api-endpoint).